# Regarding ThreadExceptionDialog dialog

Tags: c#, exception

I know that the ThreadExceptionDialog is thrown for all exceptions that occur in the program.
My problem is that the dialog form shows assembly information along with the Exception details.

Is there a way to hide the assembly information and show only the exception information?

Comment: It only occurs for exceptions on the UI thread.  Worker threads will raise the `AppDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: and they all display assembly information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "disable" this behavior completely by calling `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode()` in the `Main()` method of your application.  As far as I know, there isn't a way to hide just the assembly information from the default `ThreadExceptionDialog`.  However, if you set your application to handle `ThreadException`, you can display your own information.  If you don't override it, you get the normal `ThreadExceptionDialog` and the user may quit or continue.  Continuing is not a good outcome 99.99% of the time.

Please review the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx) document for more information.